# Replace the contents of a list rather than appending to it

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, append

Is there a way to replace the contents of a list rather than appending to it in Python 3?

I can't seem to find a function that does this.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to replace specific elements? Are those elements contiguous? Are you replacing all elements? By what rules are those elements to be replaced? Did you find Python 2 solutions but they didn't work? Etc.

Comment: Telling us you 'searched everywhere' doesn't help; what *did* you find but wasn't helpful? If that's too numerous, just leave the 'I searched' bit out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Assign to a slice of the list](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#modifying):

```
L[a:b] = M
```

If you want to replace the entire contents in-place, you could use:

```
L[:] = M
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice notation to assign back to the original list.

```
l = [4,5,6]

>>> id(l)
45206544
```

You can confirm this is the same object by checking the `id`

```
>>> l[:] = [1,2,3]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]

>>> id(l)
45206544
```